# A couple of questions about coding and testing an API

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I'm building an API in PHP using CodeIgniter framework (with an [API library](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/)), and I have a couple of quick questions:

1. I've been told that I don't need to generate a unique token for every user since it won't be an open API (since i'll use it for applications I build myself only), and that it's an unnecessary overhead in that case. Is this true?
2. Is there an easy way to test the API? I'm not sure how to do that when I want to test API authentication (i use a user/pass combo, not a token), or when passing POST parameters.

Your help is so much appreciated. I've spent so much time trying to solve the above issues. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can think of your API like any other method in the CI framework, except that instead of rendering a view, it just spits out data then ends.

Since we don't know what you're trying to do specifically, I'll answer generically.

1) - Yes, it's unnecessary overhead, but not by much. You should pass some kind of token just to make sure the call is coming from you and not just some script pinging random pages on sites. That can be static though...
http://www.yoursite.com/controller/method/token

then have your method check the passed token with a static one set in the class.

2) - just navigate to it first. If your API returns a json object, for example, it will spit it out on screen and you can verify the results there. Then to check via code, choose your medthod of request.

say your php was:

```
public function getUsers()
{
    if(isset($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token'] == 'abc123')
    {
        die(json_encode(array('users' => array('1' => 'someone', '2' => 'someone else'))));
    }
}
```

Then you call it via something like ajax for on demand requests...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yoursite.com/controller/getUsers',
    type: "POST",
    data: {token: 'abc123'}, //obviously make this more complex
    async: false,
    global: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
                // do something with your data
    }
});
```

If server side, then use cURL. The choice is yours really. For more in depth response, narrow your question down.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! what about the authentication though (to access the API)? the library I'm using mandates a user/pass, not just an API key. Also, regarding the first question, would sending the user login info through POST in each request would do the same job as the token?

Comment: Mandating a user/pass can easily be circumvented by just passing anything that could be likened to this, unless it is cross referenced somewhere on the library side. You could just make a generic user/pass and pass it with every request if you are not worried about bypassing what seems like someone's attempt at enforcing some security habits. Either way, it's your API, so you're in control of what happens. Least that's what I get from this post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're the only one using the API you can just handle the authentication with auth basic, via .htaccess, for example. It'll save you from writing extra code.

Regarding how do you test your API: you can create a rest client using the curl functions of PHP. The php manual offers a few examples to make GET and POST calls with curl.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into that. I'd like to avoid the .htaccess though.